# Show comma instead of dot - Keyboard

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Is there a way to get a comma for `edittext` instead of dot. My Keyboard is german, device is samsung.

looking for solution via `XML` not extra `listeners`.

So far i have tried

1.

```
android:digits="0123456789,"
android:inputType="number"
```

2. 

```
android:digits="0123456789,"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

3. 

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

nothing seems to work, and I still get dot. I have gone through other similar questions but they suggest managing it by adding `listener` to `edittexts`. I have a lot of `editText` and it will be much additional/unnecessary work. There should be an `XML` simple solution to this.

**Also tried**

```
val input = EditText(requireContext())
input.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,")
```

[image: enter code here]

Comment: The decimal separator should be tied to the user's chosen locale. If the keyboard is not honoring your locale, that is a bug in the keyboard, and there are hundreds of different keyboard implementations.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Custom keyboard will be too much work, I will see if i find an easier way otherwise I will go with this option.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText input = new EditText(THE_CONTEXT);
input.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
```

Comment: I mentioned i don't want to manage it programmatically. I have many edittext and adding listeners to all can be hectic and i beleive there should be solution that works for all editText that I can add to styles.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no other solution actually Create Extensions.kt class and define it in it

Comment: I guess I have to go with this option rather than creating custom keyboard. I can add it in extension, I appreciate your offer for help.

Comment: Your solution works for emulator but not for samsung x cover device. Doesn't help.         I added following code in the fragment class. ``val input = EditText(requireContext())
        input.keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,")``

Comment: does it work like this If so i can update my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244297/discussion-between-amir-dora-and-omer-seyfettin-yavuzyigit).